# Failed to convert iob to spaCy binary format

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I try to convert my IOB (token-per-line NER) files (train/test) to Spacy 3 binary format.

Example of input format (with separator "\t", no blanklines and encoding utf-8) :

```
Département B-LOCATION
des I-LOCATION
Bouches-du-Rhône    I-LOCATION
.   O
Port    B-INSTALLATION
de  I-INSTALLATION
la  I-INSTALLATION
Ciotat  I-INSTALLATION
.   O
Avant-projet    O
du  O
môle    B-INSTALLATION
Bérouard    I-INSTALLATION
au  O
port    B-INSTALLATION
de  I-INSTALLATION
La  I-INSTALLATION
Ciotat  I-INSTALLATION
.   O
```

when I run :

```sh
!python -m spacy convert -c iob -s -n 10 -b fr_core_news_sm /content/ner4archives_v0_train.iob .

!python -m spacy convert -c iob -s -n 10 -b fr_core_news_sm /content/ner4archives_v0_test.iob .
```

I have this error :

```
ValueError: [E903] The token-per-line NER file is not formatted correctly. Try checking whitespace and delimiters. See https://spacy.io/api/cli#convert
```

I saw the git directory with example data : https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/tree/master/extra/example_data/ner_example_data ; but I cannot find the difference between my data and examples.

I try to reformat my file with different kind of separators ("\t", " ", "|"), I have always the same error. In addition, i tested if I have empty tokens or labels, it is not.

anyone with leads ? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're using SpaCy with version other than `3.X`, I could create `.spacy` binary file using your input without any trouble after download `fr_core_news_sm`.

command:

```
python -m spacy convert -c iob -s -n 10 -b fr_core_news_sm C:/git/sof/test.iob .
```

output:

```
[i] Auto-detected token-per-line NER format
[i] Grouping every 10 sentences into a document.
[i] Segmenting sentences with parser from model 'fr_core_news_sm'.
[+] Generated output file (1 documents): test.spacy
```

SpaCy version : `3.1.3`